# forcing ssl for all embedded links using htaccess to tackle insecure content

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I am trying to enforce SSL on a folder (blog admin). That part is fine - all pages are SSL, but the site is generating error messages for insecure contents on the page. I can go after all those links individually, to enforce SSL on the links.
I was wondering if that could be done through htaccess alone?
This is what I have done for SSL enforcing on the admin folder:

```
#forcing https for admin folder
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com/blog/admin/$1 [R,L]
```

How can I convert all the non ssl links to ssl on the same page ?

Addition:

1) I am using wordpress 3.6 with different plugins that come along with it. Only the admin areas is SSL, and the rest of it, other than login page (that is outside of admin is also SSL) are non SSL (for example the Blog feed for the end users).

2) A few of insecure contents are coming from my own site, but then there are others which are coming from the plugins I am using. For example disqus commenting system, and flickr.

3) I can force the internal links for images, css, and jscript by simply using 'setting for permalink' on wordpress (noticed the url was provided as http and not https). Similarly, I can locate and fix the other links like this one:

> The page at https://mysite.com/blog/wp-login.php ran insecure content
>   from
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6

4) The issue is:

- If I use permalink setting, then the blog links are created as https
  instead of http, and that breaks the plugins I am using for the non
  SSL pages, for example disqus comment feed don't show up on the blog
  page. Secondly, The painful process of fixing all the non ssl links.
  Also, I can always miss out on some of them, since I am doing it
  manually. It would be really helpful, if I could enforce SSL for all
  these non SSL links using htaccess, perhaps the only easy solution.

Comment: Provide some sample of URLs that are generating `insecure content` warning.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite rules (which are in in fact redirections, when it's about HTTP to HTTPS) won't help, since by the time the initial plain HTTP request reaches the server, it's too late.

It's the links on the page you serve that must be addressed. This is generally up to the application (e.g. your PHP/CGI applcation) running on the server, not up to the server itself. The server would need to be able to process the content of the responses it sends to replace these links, not just redirect the requests (like `mod_rewrite` does).

[`mod_proxy_html`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_html.html) (distributed with Apache 2.4 or separately in earlier versions) is a module that can to in-depth processing of the response, but I'm not sure whether it can be used as a post-processing tool for PHP running on the same server, to rewrite the links it sends.
Of course, this won't fix links to external resources that are not available via `https://` anyway.